# Is it possible to have different lifecycle rules for AWS S3 prefix and remaining objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket like:

```
patha/
pathb/
pathc/
pathd/
pathe/
```

I would like to have much longer expiration on patha and pathb, thus creating 2 rules that filter on prefix.

I then want to expire all remaining objects that don't match either patha or pathb much quicker. But according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html if I specify an **empty filter**, it will apply to all objects in the bucket?

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. It is not possible to specify a "for everything else" rule.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to tag the objects under  patha/ and pathb/ and have a rule based on tags

1. Use a lambda function to tag object, and link the tag value to the object's prefix. Schedule the lambda to run before the lifecycle rules kick in so that you can tag any new objects added to patha/ and pathb/.
2. Use the "tag" parameters of your lifecycle rule and have rules based on tag